# Three.js don't strecht mesh texture (image) - make it cover its container

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I have a container which i apply an image to using a three.js and mesh.

That's how I apply my mesh to the scene:

```
this.$els = {
    el: el,
    image: el.querySelector('.ch__image') <-- size of container image is being applied to
};

this.loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
this.image = this.loader.load(this.$els.image.dataset.src);
this.sizes = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);
this.offset = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);

getSizes() {
    const { width, height, top, left } = this.$els.image.getBoundingClientRect();

    this.sizes.set(width, height);
    this.offset.set(left - window.innerWidth / 2 + width / 2, -top + window.innerHeight / 2 - height / 2)
}

createMesh() {
    this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1, 1);
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: this.image
    });

    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);

    this.mesh.position.set(this.offset.x, this.offset.y, 0);
    this.mesh.scale.set(this.sizes.x, this.sizes.y, 1);

    this.scene.add(this.mesh)
}
```

Currently images/textures are being stretched to fit the container - how can I make the behave just like `object-fit: cover` or `background-size: cover`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it with the `cover()` function presented in this code snippet. The idea is to use the aspect of your container and of the image to achieve a similar result like `background-size: cover`.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

var texture;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif', () => {
    
      cover( texture, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight );
    
      scene.background = texture;
    
    } );
    texture.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

  var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

  camera.aspect = aspect;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  
  cover( texture, aspect );

  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function cover( texture, aspect ) {

  var imageAspect = texture.image.width / texture.image.height;

  if ( aspect < imageAspect ) {

      texture.matrix.setUvTransform( 0, 0, aspect / imageAspect, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.5 );

  } else {

      texture.matrix.setUvTransform( 0, 0, 1, imageAspect / aspect, 0, 0.5, 0.5 );

  }

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
 }
 canvas {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>
```

BTW: Instead of using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`, use the dimensions of the container instead.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I encountered one issue: I have multiple textures that have to be covered. It works fine when every single one of them is inside of the viewport. But sometimes, the page is loaded and initially some of the textures have been transformed out of the viewport - in these cases, the function cover is not working - calling it afterwards again f.e. by resizing, they are being covered successfully. But how can I successfully call the functions, even if they're outside of the viewport?

Comment: Um, I'm not sure I fully understand. But if for some reasons the DOM is not yet ready, the computation might produce wrong results. Meaning you can only call `cover()` when the DOM is actually ready.

Comment: I call it inside of the `load` promise just like you did - the problem is that some textures aren't visible on start, they are being loaded on start, but not inside of the viewport. Somehow `cover()` won't work on these images.

Comment: You say these textures are at least loaded, right? What do you see in your browser console if you log `texture.image.width` and `texture.image.height`.

Comment: I see the its height and width, nothing suspicious but one thing - for some images (might be the distorted ones) I get the following warning: `THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (1044x1566) to (1024x1024)` (sizes vary).

Comment: You can avoid this warning by providing a POT textures or by setting `texture.minFilter` to `THREE.LinearFilter`. Can you please try it with the latter approach and see what happens?

Comment: Ok the problem occurred because I was applying a css `matrix` to the images - rotation included - removing this and solely adding transform on the x-axis solved the issue. Anyways, would you recommend to remove the code from `texture.minFilter` again?

Comment: I would keep it since texture resizing distorts the original image dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I create a Canvas element, and edit the size of image by CanvasContext.drwaImage, then make a CanvasTexture. It works

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

function createCoverTexture(
  url: string,
  width: number,
  height: number
): Promise<THREE.CanvasTexture> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const aspect = width / height;

    const image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

    image.onload = () => {
      const [sw, sh, left, top] =
        image.height < image.width / aspect
          ? [
              image.height * aspect,
              image.height,
              image.width / 2 - (image.height * aspect) / 2,
              0,
            ]
          : [
              image.width,
              image.width / aspect,
              0,
              image.height / 2 - image.width / aspect / 2,
            ];

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.width = sw;
      canvas.height = sh;

      ctx?.drawImage(image, left, top, sw, sh, 0, 0, sw, sh);

      resolve(new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas));
    };

    image.onerror = reject;

    image.src = url;
  });
}
```