# Three.js - Take up all available space with plane geometry (emulate background-size:cover property)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to build a three.js scene containing a large plane geometry that should take up all the available space, regardless of the aspect ratio of the viewport.

I have made a rough fiddle to highlight the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/nq2oy9ca/1/

Using the following resize function:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight); 
});
```

the image is only scaled if there are changes to the y axis of the viewport - it doesn't react to changes on the x axis.

This means that it will take up all space only if the viewport has a narrow aspect ratio: if the aspect ratio becomes wide enough, the background will become visible to the the left and the right.

Removing the function prevents the image from being resized at all.

I reckon the result could be achieved by dynamically updating the camera distance ( camera.position.z ) whenever the viewport is resized, but i don't know how that value correlates to the viewport \ canvas size.

Any feedback would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Three.js don't strecht mesh texture (image) - make it cover its container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290458/three-js-dont-strecht-mesh-texture-image-make-it-cover-its-container) You can run the code snippet on the first answer, and it does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Looks like it - thank you :)